# VBA Excel- Get Cell value and associated rows into another worksheet based on User Input

Tags: excel, vba

All-

I'm very new to VBA and I really need help. I have a worksheet called Sheet 1 that looks like this (This is where the data will be copied from)

[image]

and another sheet (Sheet2) that looks like this (this is where the data will be copied to). Notice that the order is not the same as above

[image]

When a user types in a place such as "Paris" I want it to copy all corresponding values with "Paris" and it's associated rows. So the end result should look like this
[image]

Here is the code I have so far. Right now I can pull all the corresponding values based on the Users input, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the associated rows. Please help! Any input will be highly appreciated.

```
Dim x As String
Dim K As Long
Dim ct As Variant
Dim r As Range
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Dim w2 As Worksheet
Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
x = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Place")
w1.Activate
K = 3
For Each r In Intersect(Range("C3:C3" & a), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
ct = r.Value
If InStr(ct, x) > 0 And ct <> "" Then
r.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
K = K + 1
w2.Activate
End If
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not tack on additional questions to your question. The original question was using VBA to obtain your list, so by you editing a new `VLOOKUP` question makes this question too broad and invalidates prior answers. If you have a new question, please [start a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You may add a link in your new question that points to this one for context if you like. You may want to take a look at [ask] for more information. I have rolled back your question to keep it on topic for Stack Overflow. Thanks!!

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. I apologize. I'll start a new question.

Comment: No need to apologize. I just wanted to make sure you were aware :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the entire range to an array for quicker looping, then once the array finds a match to your inputstring, rewrite the values to your 2nd sheet.

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, wsArr()
    set ws1 = thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")
    set ws2 = thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet2")

    With ws1
        wsArr = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(LastRow(ws1), 4)).Value
    End With

    Dim findStr As String
    findStr = InputBox("Please Enter Place")

    Dim i As Long, r as long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws2
        .Range("A3:D3").Value = array("Place", "Name", "Thing", "Animal")
        For i = LBound(wsArr) To UBound(wsArr)
            If wsArr(i, 3) = findStr Then
                r = LastRow(ws2) + 1
                .Cells(r, 1) = wsArr(i, 3)
                .Cells(r, 2) = wsArr(i, 1)
                .Cells(r, 3) = wsArr(i, 2)
                .Cells(r, 4) = wsArr(i, 4)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function LastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

For even better performance, consider doing a `COUNTIF()` to get the count of the number of `findStr` occurances in your range - that way you can use this value to `ReDim` a new array in order to write the matches there, then write the array to `Sheet2` all at once.

Comment: And unfortunately, although my sub was named `test()`, I didn't actually test it. So let me know if any issues arise.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly! How would I modify the code if I have more  than 4 columns in Sheet 1(Say 10) and I only need to pull 6 of those columns into Sheet 2? I was playing with the code and I changed the ranges and the Array values but I get a subscript out of range error. Sorry for so many questions, I'm really trying to understand this for the future

Comment: The **4** in `.Cells(LastRow(ws1), 4)).Value` is how many columns in your sheet1 that you wanted. You would change that to 10 for 10 columns. In sheet2, the **4** in `.Cells(r, 4) = ...` (inside the `For i = ` loop) will determine the output column.

Comment: Then to decide which columns you wanted to _pull from_ would be the last number in `= wsArr(i, 3)` (the `3` means you are pulling from column 3 in Sheet1).

Comment: And finally, the `.Range("A3:D3").Value = array("Place", "Name", "Thing", "Animal")` will be your headers in Sheet2. You would need to change the `:D3` to the last column, and also add more headers to the array.

Comment: ohhhhh ok. Now I get it. Thank you so much for the explanation and also your help.

Comment: HI I have added another level of complexity to my initial question. My question has been updated. I tried using the Application.Workheetfunction.Vlookup but I get this error "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class". I'm not sure how to get past this error

Comment: @C-Lo You absolutely cannot update your question to include a completely different question! Not only is your new question now too broad, but you just invalidated the answers to your prior question. Please take a look at [ask]. Unfortunately, you will have to [start a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).